# Prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

My work: assume, for contradiction, that this is not true. Then $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Then, there exist $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\frac{p}{q}$; this implies that $a+\sqrt{b}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under multiplication, being $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies that  $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2=\frac{p^2}{q^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ as well; so it would be $a+\sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

But this is a contradiction, since the sum of a nonzero rational number and an irrational number is an irrational number.

My questions:

(i) is the proof correct?

(ii) The hypothesis of $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ are necessary to write $\sqrt{b}$ and to avoid the fact that, if $a=b=0$, then there is no contradiction in this argument (or similar arguments)?

Comment: The second paragraph might look clearer if you write "Then there exists... such that... and..."

Comment: @Divide1918 Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit it; in my first language it sounds better with the hypothetical form.

Comment: Why don't you simply say that $\sqrt{a + \sqrt b} \in \Bbb Q \implies \sqrt b = \left(\sqrt{a + \sqrt b}\right)^2 - a \in \Bbb Q$. There is no need in writing $\frac p q$ etc.

Comment: @Aqua, WhatsUp: You are right, this is way cleaner. I didn't see it. Thanks. Do you think my proof is still valid?

Comment: @ZaWarudo Tokiyo tomare!